# Sorted array with .sort() doesn't equal manually sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```js
if([5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2].sort() == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]){console.log("It works")}
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] == [5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2].sort());
```

Why does it return false ? Aren't they the same ?
}

Comment: Because you are comparing two different objects and this way their reference is compared, which is not the same. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: Aside from the comparing arrays thing, it's probably even easier to *check* if an array is sorted, as opposed to comparing it against an already sorted array.